# Descarga en Null

Tags: php, javascript, html, excel, pdf

En mi boton `"Descargar excel"` tengo un `onclick` que lleva a la siguiente function en `JS`:

```
function downloadExcel(status)
{
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/WareHouse/reporte.php?status="+status,
    type: "GET",
    success:function(status)
    {
            console.log("Entre a download excel");
            var tmpElemento = document.createElement('a');
            var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
            var tabla_div = document.getElementById('actives');
            tmpElemento.href = data_type + ', ' + tabla_div;
            //Asignamos el nombre a nuestro EXCEL
            tmpElemento.download = 'InventoryToReorder.xls';
            tmpElemento.click();
    }
  });
}
```

Estoy mandando llamar un archivo llamado `reporte.php` mismo que se utilizo para generar un PDF, el problema que tengo es que si me descarga el `excel` pero al abrirlo este en la celda `A1` es decir en la primera solamente dice `null` no dice mas. Cual podria ser el problema por el cual no me muestra siquiera los nombres de la columnas?

`reporte.php`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <?php echo'<title>Inventory To Reorder</title>';?>
</head>

<body onload="window.print()">
  <?php echo '<img src="http://localhost/WareHouse/assets/img/Esterline.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height:6%; width:23%; margin-top:40px; margin-left:40px;"/>';?>
    <?php  echo '<center style="margin-top:120px; font-size:14pt;"><strong>Inventory To Reorder</strong></center>';?>
  <?php  echo '<label><center>____________________________________________________________________________</center></label><br>';?>
<?php

require_once('apis/connection.php');
    if(isset($_GET['status']))
    {
      $status = $_GET["status"];
      //Trae todos los item que esten por debajo de su minimo en stock.
      $connection = new MySqlServerConnection();
      $query = "SELECT i.description_item,i.quantity,u.name_unit,i.reorder_Level,i.target_Stock,l.name_location,i.commentt,io.quantity_s,i.status
      FROM inventory_list AS i
      INNER JOIN unit_mesurement AS u ON id_unit = fkUnit
      INNER JOIN location AS l on id_location = fkLocation
      INNER JOIN inventory_output as io on id_output = fkInventory
      WHERE i.quantity <= i.reorder_Level OR i.status = 1";
      $result = $connection->executeQuery($query,array($status));
      if ($result > 0) {
        var_dump($result);
      //echo $query;
  ?>
  <center>
            <table class="table table-striped xd" border="1px;" id="actives">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 3%;">Description</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%;">Quantity</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%;">Usage</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%;">Name Unit</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%;">Reorder Level</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%;">Target Stock</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%;">Area</th>
                    <th style="width: 3%;">Comment</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php
                $arraycount=count($result);
                $i=0;
                $total=0;
                while ($i < $arraycount)
                {
                  ?>
                            <tr>
                             <td><center><?php echo $result[$i]['description_item']; ?></td>
                             <td><p style="color:red;" ><?php echo $result[$i]['quantity']; ?></p></td>
                            <td>
                             <?php
                             $qs = $result[$i]['quantity_s'];
                             switch (true) {
                                case ($qs >= 1000 && $qs <= 2000) :
                                  echo " 1000 a 2000 SEMANAL";
                                 break;

                                 case ($qs >= 100 && $qs <= 200) :
                                  echo " 100 a 200 SEMANAL Y/O QUINCENAL";
                                 break;
                             }
                              ?>
                             </td>
                             <td><?php echo $result[$i]['name_unit']; ?></td>
                             <td><?php echo $result[$i]['reorder_Level']; ?></td>
                             <td><?php echo $result[$i]['target_Stock']; ?></td>
                             <td><?php echo $result[$i]['name_location']; ?></td>
                             <td><?php echo $result[$i]['commentt']; ?></center></td>
                            </tr>
                <?php $i++;
              }
                ?>
            </table><br><br>
  </center>
      <?php
      }
      //}
    }
  ?>
  
</body>
```

Comment: El error que te sale indica que no pudo recuperar el DOM fragment para el elemento con id `tabla`. Estás ejecutando esto en el mismo momento que el código para generar el PDF?

Comment: Debería funcionar. Es más, excel toma un archivo con la extensión xls(x) incluso si el contenido es un HTML, y lo intenta abrir sin lío (si acaso te pregunta si lo quieres abrir). De nuevo, el error tiene que ver con que no logra cargar la tabla en la variable, nada más; por eso mi pregunta. Si muestras dónde estás "ejecutando" esas dos funciones, es más fácil ayudar; la pregunta genérica "ese código funcionaría" dificilmente la podamos responder.

Comment: Por favor agrega el html generado por php, ya que no creo que sea un problema directamente de php

Comment: A ver si comprendo bien: quieres que cuando se pulse el botón se descargue el archivo excel, pero sin tener la tabla presente en la página. ¿Es eso correcto?

Comment: y ese archivo se referencia en algún momento en tu `reporte.php` porque eso no se ve. Trata de poner siempre un [mcve]

Comment: Y tampoco se ve el html del boton? Lo generas por javascript o como es que tampoco lo veo en `reporte.php`?

Comment: El html del boton, lo puse al principio  desde que formule la pregunta  en su onclick haho referencia a la function del js. Como mandar a llamar el reporte entraria en el problema que tengo como mando a llamar ese archivo, ademas en el reporte.php como te daras cuenta tengo un window.print que es para generar el pdf, ¿Que necesitaria cambiar para generar un excel? Teniendo en cuenta que la tabla la tengo dentro del mismo y que en el js me marca error en la linea que comente anteriormente, ya que segun yo espera una tabla dentro de un html

Comment: El boton, digamos lo asi, se encuentra en el index, mi pagina principal

Comment: Entonces incluye tu página principal, tal vez tenga que ver en que no funcione no crees?

Comment: @VirusDetected si sabes que las capturas no son de ayuda verdad?

Comment: Es que ya he descrito todo lo ms detalladamente posible, no se que mas, mi pagina principal es index.html para el boton de exportar a excel es solamente un input con un onclick que lleva a una function en un archivo.js. la tabla y los datos se ejecutan los tiene reporte.php, como dije ese codigo como esta es para generar un PDF le tengo que cambiar algo ahi, ya que como puedes notar tengo un window.print(), en la function downloadExcel() tengo que mandar a llamar el archivo?como? me marca error en outerHTML, (segun yo porque espera una tabla dentro de mi index) pero todo eso esta en el php.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87254/discussion-between-virusdetected-and-ruslan-lopez).

Comment: Ya he editado la pregunta con el resultado.

Comment: @VirusDetected pareces estar haciendo la misma pregunta varias veces.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87311/discussion-on-question-by-virusdetected-descarga-en-null).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que utilices PHPExcel https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Tu llamada debería ser así:

```
function downloadExcel(status)
{
    url = "http://localhost/WareHouse/reporte.php?status="+status;
    window.open(url,"_blank"); 
}
```

Y tu archivo PHP algo así:

```
<?php
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');//Change to your location

if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
die('This example can be run only in web browsers');

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set document properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("StackOverFlow")
                         ->setLastModifiedBy("StackOverFlow")
                         ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Document")
                         ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Document")
                         ->setDescription("Document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
                         ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
                         ->setCategory("Result file");
require_once('apis/connection.php');
if(isset($_GET['status']))
{
  $status = $_GET["status"];
  //Trae todos los item que esten por debajo de su minimo en stock.
  $connection = new MySqlServerConnection();
  $query = "SELECT i.description_item,i.quantity,u.name_unit,i.reorder_Level,i.target_Stock,l.name_location,i.commentt,io.quantity_s,i.status
  FROM inventory_list AS i
  INNER JOIN unit_mesurement AS u ON id_unit = fkUnit
  INNER JOIN location AS l on id_location = fkLocation
  INNER JOIN inventory_output as io on id_output = fkInventory
  WHERE i.quantity <= i.reorder_Level OR i.status = 1";
  $result = $connection->executeQuery($query,array($status));
  if ($result > 0)
  {
      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A1', 'Description');
      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B1', 'Quantity');
      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('C1', 'Usage');
      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('D1', 'Name Unit');
      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('E1', 'Reorder Level');
      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('F1', 'Target Stock');
      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('G1', 'Area');
      $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('H1', 'Comment');


      $arraycount=count($result);
      $i=0;
      $total=0;
      while ($i < $arraycount)
      {
        $j=$i+2;
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A'.$j, $result[$i]['description_item']);
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B'.$j, $result[$i]['quantity']);
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('C'.$j, $result[$i]['quantity_s'];);
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('D'.$j, $result[$i]['name_unit'];);
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('E'.$j, $result[$i]['reorder_Level'];);
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('F'.$j, $result[$i]['target_Stock'];);
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('G'.$j, $result[$i]['name_location'];);
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('H'.$j, $result[$i]['commentt'];);
$i++;
        }
    }
}

// Rename worksheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Result');


// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
$nombre=date("d-m-y H:i");
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Reporte_'.$nombre.'.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

No lo he probado, por favor dime si funcionó.

Comment: El inicio del  <?php, lo estas cerrando con el exit; ?

Comment: No es necesario el cierre de php ?> pero si se lo quieres poner está bien.

Answer (score 1):

Yo suelo usar ajax para llamar cosas de esta manera, y sé que alguna vez me ha fallado porque me faltaban los `cache`, `contentType`, `processData`...
Aunque en tu caso es get, no estoy seguro si cambia algo.

```
$.ajax({ url: url,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
            console.log(output);
        },
        error: function(salida) {
            console.log(salida);
        },
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,

    });
```

también suelo hacer las llamadas de esta otra manera:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var formData = new FormData();
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        var response = request.responseText;
        console.log(response);
    }
};
request.open('POST', url);
request.send(formData);
```